# Vue js http request loop

Tags: vue.js, vue-resource

I'm trying to create a live search form which is calling a http request whenever there is user input. So far the live searching works well, but the http request results in a loop. This problem shows up when I'm assigning the catalog_items to this.items.

Vue.js

```
Vue.filter('searchFor', function (value, searchString) {

    var result = [];

    if(!searchString || searchString.length < 2){
        return value;
    }

    searchString = searchString.trim().toLowerCase();

    this.fetchData(searchString);
    result = this.items;

    return result;
})

new Vue({
    el: '#searchform',
    data: {
        searchString: "",
        items: []
    },
    methods: {
        fetchData: function (name) {
            this.$http.get('api_url' + name )
            .then(function(response){
                var data = response.data;
                var catalog_items = data['catalog_items'];
                this.items = catalog_items;
            })
        }
    }
})
```

The html search input:

```
<input type="text" v-model="searchString" placeholder="Enter your search terms" />
<ul>
    <li v-for="item in catalog_items | searchFor searchString">
        <p>@{{item.name}}</p>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes, I want to make a http request only when the user input changes.

Comment: You're not doing anything with `value`, though. How does `catalog_items` figure in? It's not defined in your Vue data. It doesn't seem like you're filtering anything. You just want to `watch(searchString)`

Comment: You're right. I'm not filtering anything and I just want to watch searchString.. In the mean time I changes catalog_items to items

Comment: You should revise your question so we can see the problem you're having.